# useNavigate doesn't load page when navigating between siblings component

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm working at a react-js app using react-router-dom v6

I try to simplify my framework to make it clearer.

**MainRouter.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <NavBar/>
  <Routes>     
      <Route exact path="/"  element={<HomePage/>}></Route>
      <Route path="item"  element={<ShowItem/>}>
        <Route path=":itemId"  element={<ShowItem/>}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
  </Routes>
```

The navbar includes a search bar s.t. I'm able to search different items: "item/1", "item/2", ... For sake of semplicity, I replace the search bar with a button which try to redirect always to item 12

**NavBsr.js**

```
return (
    [...]
    <button onClick={()=>navigate("/item/12")}>Click</button>
);
```

If I'm in any page but "item/*", the navigation works as expected. Ex. if I'm at "homepage", the button redirects to "item/12"

However, the strange behaviour happens if my current page is "item/*", ex. "item/1". In this case, if I press the button the url changes to "item/12" but the content doesn't load: the correct content is loaded only if I manually refresh the page

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ShowItem` component should "listen" for changes to the `itemId` route param so it can handle fetching data or running any logic that depends on this value.

Use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `itemId` route param.

Example:

```
const { itemId } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (itemId) {
    // handle logic using new itemId value
  }
}, [itemId]);
```